# How to remove gVim's fat bottom border (and resize grip)?

Tags: gtk, gnome-terminal, vim, gvim

My gVim has this annoying bottom border:

[image: fat border gvim]

I wish it didn't and looked more like gnome-terminal for example:

[image: pretty gnome-terminal]

Is there any way for gVim to look like that?

**UPDATE: There is! Here's a screenshot after adding settings from Jeremy Cantrell's and my own answers:**

[image: epilogue]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I use to get rid of the resize handle in the corner. Just put this in ~/.gtkrc-2.0

```
style "no-resize-handle"
{
    GtkWindow::resize-grip-height = 0
    GtkWindow::resize-grip-width = 0
}

class "GtkWidget" style "no-resize-handle"
```

Answer (score 13):

Ok so setting this in my `.gtkrc-2.0` alleviates the problem:

```
style "vimfix" {
  bg[NORMAL] = "#242424" # this matches my gvim theme 'Normal' bg color.
}
widget "vim-main-window.*GtkForm" style "vimfix"
```

Screenshot:

[image: Border is the same color as vim's Normal bg]

**This still doesn't fix the resize triangle in the lower right.**

Comment: This worked for me too in 13.04, but I had to create `.gtkrc-2.0` since it didn't exist yet.

Comment: This worked for me in 14.04, while the marked answer didn't (make sure you use vim-gtk and not vim-gnome).

Comment: Could you use the same technique to edit the top border (the title bar)?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have a blank line in your `statusline` format codes. Can you tell us what ":set statusline" shows? Maybe we can help you format another one, or you can set to something simple yourself, or turn it off altogether.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Even if I change the statusline, the light grey border on the bottom still remains along with the grey resize thingy.